# Using Rack::Attack to throttle Basic Auth

Tags: basic-authentication, throttling, rack-middleware, rackattack

I have `gem rack-attack` setup for my app. I want to start throttling basic auth authentication based on IP.

My basic auth code setup like so:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.middleware.insert_after(::Rack::Lock, '::Rack::Auth::Basic', ENV['RAILS_ENV') do |u, p|
  [u, p] == [ENV['BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME'], ENV['BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD']]
end
```

I'd imagine my rack attack would contain something like this:

```
# config/initializers/rack_attack.rb
Rack::Attack.throttle('req/ip', limit: 2, period: 60.seconds) do |req| req.ip 
    # what should belong here???
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my [github comment](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack/issues/47#issuecomment-37134906) about this question.